# Are professional-to-professional questions within the site scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Rationales behind the order of applying the torso straps of a Kendrick Extrication Device](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/590/rationales-behind-the-order-of-applying-the-torso-straps-of-a-kendrick-extricati)

This question refers to the above question on the main site. The main contention seems to be that it has low applicability to the health and well being of the general public. This is because it is referring to a device that is used specifically by EMS and similar entities for rescue extractions and immobilization.

However, it does have merit as a question between specific professionals, i.e. EMS practitioners of various areas and abilities since the application of the straps in different orders could have health implications we don't know about.

Is the question too narrow and focused, or will we define health to include specific subsets such as EMS to EMS or Doctor to Docter, etc?

Comment: If it is determined that they are in scope, I will remove my DV and close vote.

Comment: Thanks for having asked John!

Answer (score 20):

That's awesome: Professionals asking professionals about the questions *they* have in this field.

***Yes, on topic!***

It would be a bit backward-thinking to exclude the questions that *professionals* would actually have for a site like this… *because they're not "general" enough?*

Think about that.

You would be excluding the interests of the the very people who will (hopefully) drive the **best** content of this site. You would be excluding the people who will make this site "work".

#### Embrace these specialized, long-tailed questions

Many sites have the problem that they strive to become *soooo* generic and applicable to all, that they settle into a Wikipedia-like scope where only uninspired questions that anyone could ask are allowed. And they’ve all been asked 100 times before on every other site on that subject. No thank you.

> low applicability to … the general public

To throw in a bit of historical context, this sounds an awful lot like folks looking for things that are *too localized.* "Too localized" once describe questions involving *"…very tiny geographic regions or vanishingly small periods of time",* and it's an out-modded artifact we got rid of a long time ago, *good riddance.* Too localized is no longer a valid reason to flag or close a post.

We should not close questions because "it is too narrow and focused."

If the professionals want to use this site for their specialized interests in this field, you've gotta love it. Failing to embrace these questions with *both* arms would be a big mistake.

> *"To attract experts, you need a site where people are asking very interesting and challenging questions, not the basic questions found on every other Q&A site.*
>
> ***Remember, the pro sites WILL attract the enthusiasts, but not the other way around!"***
>
> *— [**Blog Post, Your New Site: Asking the First Questions**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)*

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I had been thinking that it would be of low interest/applicability, but after the reasoning from Shu and yourself, I have changed my thinking. Appreciate the insight.

Comment: I have no problem with this, but presume they will remain unanswered until other professionals come along to answer them. Is that a problem for the site?

Comment: +1 for  pro sites WILL attract the enthusiasts, but not the other way around

Comment: @anongoodnurse Generally no. I am typically **way** more worried about sites that have 100% answer rates since the earliest days simply because their questions are mundane and easily answerable. But if you're asking intriguing questions (that are simply too specialized to be answered by "anyone"), folks will find it through search... and even the specialists simply *love* to show off a bit on occasion with what they know. Hypothetically, if nothing is getting answered, folks have likely long since stopped caring about this site, but that seems unlikely under this "too hard to answer" scenario.

Answer (score 5):

Such questions should be on-topic in my opinion. The same issue exists on other SE sites, Stack Overflow or Server Fault being excellent examples. On these two:

- some of the questions can be understood and answered by a non-professional-but-interested public,
- some can only be understood but not answered by such a public
- and finally, some are tricky questions for professional geeks.

This sounds natural to me. On top of that, accepting professional-to-professional questions would be an excellent way to attract professionals on this site: on top of answering questions - so giving time to others -, they would also be in a position to ask their own questions and to have them answered - so finding their own interest.

Comment: Well reasoned. I would like to see another meta answer on this, but for now I have retracted and answered on the question.