# I think the reason the site attracts personal questions is because of its name

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Say you have a concern about your habit, what do you say when you meet a doctor?

> Ok, since I was 3 years old, I have Had the habit of placing my pointer finger on my right and left temple. I used to put my right pointer finger on my right temple when I was watching something. [...]

This is a description taken from [What do I have? Is this a habit or something weird?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/1940/99). Many many more examples like that are asked on Health. I don't have any number on hand to advocate my claim, but I think they have some commons:

- Asked from a new user, even they are "trusted" user who has 101 rep when opening their account on Health
- Mistakenly treat SE, a site for asking questions **based on facts**, as a doctor, someone who answers **your problem**

Yes we already have the disclaimer to remind them about that, but I think we need to find the source of misunderstanding. In my opinion, it's the site name. From a normal person who doesn't have much medical knowledge view point (like me), health buildings are hospitals, which will answer my problem. The places for gaining knowledge are medical universities.

So, if we want to discourage problem asking questions and encourage knowledge asking questions, we should make the site work more like a med school rather than a hospital. And in my opinion it should start right from the name.

**My proposal**: *health* reminds me to hospital, while *medical* reminds me to med school

If we decide to:

- **Keep using Health**: then I still hold my point in [Should professionals answer non-professional questions in layman term?](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/399/99). If the site is organize like a hospital, then the answerers are somewhat like doctors. And doctors should explain easy to understand answers.
- **Change to Medical**: then we won't need the disclaimer, or reference in the answers. They are all good layers to protect our health, but a unnecessary hindrances for sharing knowledge. Looking at other sharing knowledge SE sites like Physics or Mathematics, how frequently do you see a link in an answer? And if you see one, do you think that that link is for "hey! I don't making things up, I have proof for my claims" or "hey! while this bit is not really relevant to the topic, but it is interesting. Check it out!”?

[A chat room was set up to discuss this idea](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28979/about-the-name-of-the-site). Please join us!

Comment: I completely agree. [There is an Area51 proposal for Medicine.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86048/medicine), but I’m not convinced that anything that would be *on topic* there is *off topic* here, and many of them that people might think fall into the converse bin are actually personal medical advice questions.

Comment: there are some sites have their sister, like Mathematics and MathOverflow, Physics and PhysicsOverflow (this one is not belonged to SE). The former site can be asked for any questions, but the latter ones are kept only for professionals who actually work on the fields. Should we follow this path?

Comment: That’s how I was thinking of it when I wrote [this](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/20453/115131), but I think for  two sites to be the right tack requires both (A) enough people/questions to fuel two sites, and (B) substantial ranges of **appropriate** questions that are unique to each. It’s not clear to me that either is the case at this point.

Comment: Right. Anyway, do you think that Health should be renamed to Medical? Because the proposed site only focus on medicine

Comment: I think you described a very real problem very well, and also saw its cause. I don't know for sure *which* term will create the right expectations of the site focus, but I also see that the current name creates the wrong ones. We may need a bit more thought about what to change the name to, but a change will almost certainly be a good thing.

Comment: @rumtscho so you think that we really need to change the name? I have add more information about the consequences if we decide to change (or not).

Comment: @Ooker I'm actually not so glad about your edit. I see the two questions as mostly unrelated, and coupling them or requiring one solution for both makes everything more complicated. As for what I think of a change: The probability that it improves matters is not that high, but it almost certainly won't worsen them. And as we have a problem and no better idea for a solution, it's certainly worth a shot.

Comment: @rumtscho how about I make the consequences part to be an answer? For your latter idea, I don't know if this will be changed. The other mods don't have any response.