# Why is a personal medical questions not closed, while its answer has already supervised?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

For example, this question: [I haven't been truly hungry in a few years](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/937/99). A couple lines of it:

> I am starting to get a little concerned about something. I haven't felt truly hungry in a few years. I just eat because after a day or two of not eating I feel like the nutrients are necessary for my body, but it's not because I'm hungry.

As you can see, this is absolutely a personal medical question, and should be close immediately in Health. However, I notice that this question has one answer, and while the question doesn't get closed, the answer gets "closed":

> Some of the information contained in this post requires additional references. Please edit to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or deleted.

Surely this question has been supervised, as the answer has been disqualified by the post-notice. But why is this question not closed as too personal too?

Comment: Where is your downvote/comment/flag? I must have missed it.

Comment: @anongoodnurse isn't asking this in meta a kind of flagging?

Comment: No, it's more like using a shotgun to kill an annoying housefly. Start with the flyswatter. That means start with what *you* can reasonably do: down vote, comment, flag, raise the matter in the chat site for others to see and address if they so choose. If every close-worthy question was brought up in meta, we'd have too many unhelpful questions here. This is another question calling for the mods to do something that ideally the community should be doing. It's ok for the mods to wait until the community is large enough to do this themselves. Or not. But it's the choice of the mods.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Good point. Now, if you are mad at me, please notice that I asked this question before I learnt that the mods didn't have to have responsibility to react to everything. Also, with the answer of Atl LED, a couple of edits in my question will convert it to a generic question, then it will be helpful again.

Comment: Please notice you asked in comments after you learned all of the above.

Comment: @anongoodnurse are you referring to [this](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/430/why-is-a-personal-medical-questions-not-closed-while-its-answer-has-already-sup#comment2366_430)? If so, then not quite. Before reading your next comment, I still think that asking in meta is just another kind of flag. I do this all the time in other sites, no one complains about this. But anyway, most of them are graduated.

Comment: *"I do this all the time in other sites, no one complains..."*  By "nobody complains", do you mean your questions never receive down votes (a quiet way of complaining on meta sites)?

Comment: @anongoodnurse well, except this site, and of course I can't remember correctly every time I get a meta DV, but in general, I can say I'm sure about it. [Source](http://stackapps.com/q/3082/29559)

Comment: Hey, I find [this one](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7181/80007) gets a DV :D. But anyway, even for a bad meta question, a good answer (based on the vote number) still makes that question has value, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the question is definitely a personal medical question, and I just VTC'ed it.  In addition I included a comment, because I think it's rude and not helpful to the OP if we don't give them a little more.

Further, even if this question was taken in its general sense it should probably be closed for being too broad.  IMO the generalization of the question is "What can lead to reduced appetite in a average adult besides psychological concerns?"

The answer is so many different things it would be silly to guess without more information.  Many of the problems could be easily checked for just by palpating (from a skilled practitioner).

As to the later part of your question, this community does seem to be much harsher on answers than questions, which is probably appropriate.  Bad answers here might have "higher" consequences than on other sites.  Further, by staying "Health" instead of "Medical" (which it seems like there is [some support to switch](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/407/i-think-the-reason-the-site-attracts-personal-questions-is-because-of-its-name)), I feel like we are implicitly opening ourselves up to these questions.

I find that when I scroll through the questions on the site, a great many of them still seem personal, and that it would take far more effort than I'm willing to put it to VTC all of them.

Comment: "...it would take far more effort than I'm willing to put it to VTC all of them." Precisely. We need a lot more users willing to do *some* of the work, rather than expecting a few users (e.g. the mods) to do all of the work. This question is months old.

Comment: I have convert this question to a more generic one. It would be great if you can make some edits to suit it with the new question. Thanks