# Is this question worthy of reopening?

Tags: discussion

Irony of ironies, I posted comments below [Jon Ericson's hopeful and optimistic meta answer](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/775/169) saying I didn't mind answering questions about a sore throat because we all get them, and the answer is likely to be helpful for a number of future (and present) users.

So, as I do when I'm here, I looked at the front page, and there's a sore throat question (well, a [painless tonsillitis](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/13683/169) question) which I'm happy to answer, because it could help others...

When I first came here, it was with heady excitement about the difference we might make on the internet. A site better than Yahoo answers, even WebMD? I'm all for that.

As I said in my comments, though, all too often, the baby is thrown out with the bathwater here. **This question is of general interest, is answerable, and has the potential to do good to future users** (with some tag edits, which I didn't do).

There's a kneejerk reaction to close anything that smells like a personal medical question, when it can be edited and saved.

Can this question be saved?

<sub>I don't know, maybe I'm the only one who is actually happy upon seeing such a funky throat, because it's something I can actually discuss intelligently with the patient. As opposed to someone coming in for progressive weakness who has diffuse muscle atrophy and fasciculations that they are unaware of, and I have to tell them that they need to see a neurologist for further testing knowing damn well that they have ALS and I can't possibly tell them that 15 minutes after just meeting them for the first time...</sub>

Comment: Excellent question.  We will need to address this in our reformation... When a question is good at its root but written as advice request, I've been drastically rewriting them as topical questions, then answering them.  When I said I learned from your answers, part was how you used advice/diagnosis type questions to educate on the general topic.  Like "what's this mole" to discuss what alarm skin lesion signs are.  I think it can be done, but how would you do it in a way that distinguishes it clearly from medical advice questions?

Comment: I'm thinking out loud, but I'm wondering if it's possible to establish a clear format for asking and answering general differential diagnosis questions that are clearly differentiated from individual advice questions...or whether people may not see the difference and start asking individual advice questions again.  DDX is at the heart of medicine and it was part of what I'd hoped the site could do, but it's a fine line with advice sometimes.

Comment: Also +1 for "When I first came here, it was with heady excitement about the difference we might make on the internet."  I so very felt the same way.

Comment: Yes, it can be saved. In fact, I think the only step one needs to take is remove the personal image. Then, it is absolutely clear that personal advice is not tolerated but general questions are. One can include stock images in their answer, so that's not a problem.

Comment: @DoctorWhom After the reshape, we might try that. Right now, people wouldn't get the difference...

Comment: I originally closed the question because it was "What do I have?". The edit does make it much more on topic, and more important, on topic with the intended "future" state of health. I have reopened it, but if the original user objects to the substantial editing, it may need to be closed again.

Comment: @JohnP - Of course. I understand. Thanks for reopening.

Comment: I think by editing it in this way, it also very neatly sidesteps the diagnosis trap of "Yes you have X", which is what we originally wanted to avoid. This allows the "This is *most likely* X, but could possibly be Y or Z." type of answer.

Comment: Right. This has always been my stance. Unfortunately I was completely alone.

Comment: Nice save. I've been able to salvage a few questions this way, but they're few and far between that are worth the effort. And the ALS thing... ugh.

Comment: Should we let the image stay there? That makes it very personal? Maybe the answered can provide example pictures...

Comment: I think the image can stay. I will provide images in my answer. But I'm in and out all day; it will take me some time before I can get to it.

Comment: The image makes it personal but the image is essential to the question. It has to stay.

Comment: I think it's great to answer, for the same reasons as you mention.  I also am not opposed to radically changing questions when necessary to make unanswerable into answerable, because it's preferable to not answering it, or ending up with a "my mom says drink vinegar" as the only response.

Comment: A once personal image as central to the question and not personal advice? Then it has to be declared an 'example image' as well – _always_. And how about changing such images into a reveal/teaser hidden way? I imagine some pictures to be quite out-grossing quite a few potential visitors.

Comment: @CareyGregory - ALS is uncommon. That actually happened to me three times! Each time a brand new patient, each time it had progressed far  beyond the stage when it first should have been seen.

Comment: @LangLangC I wouldn't worry about pictures being gross on a medical site as long as they're not gratuitous or explicitly sexual.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I want to upvote your last comment but an upvote doesn't really fit. Three times? Geez.

Comment: @LangLangC +1 I’ve just gone ahead and made that change a reality

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma I vehemently object to that change. It's a photo of tonsils, not mangled bodies or bare genitals. Almost everyone on the planet can look in a mirror, open their mouth, and see that image, so I really can't imagine what you're protecting them from. In fact, if that image upsets someone then it's better they just stay away from medical sites. Doing mamby-pamby things like hiding photos isn't how we professionalize this site. I think that accomplishes quite the opposite.

Comment: @CareyGregory I do see your point. Feel free to rollback then.

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma Thank you.